# Javascript: extract an array by keys listed in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get array `c` which will list members of array `b`, which keys are listed in array `a`, in Javascript. Keys are entirely arbitrary.

For example, I got:

```
a = [0, 3, 16];
b = [456, 343453, 34534, 564, 4564, 4545, 456, 5, 54645, 3453, 345345, 3543, 44554, 4545, 4545, 454353, 34534345, 345345, 345345, 457556, 43434, 35354];
```

And I want array consisting of 1st, 4th, and 17th member of array b. Is there a way, beside pushing each member into new array, like:

```
c = extractArray(b, a);
function extractArray(source, section) {
    var target = [];
    for(i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {
        target.push(source[section[i]]);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looks easy, loop over `a` get element and get the element at the index from `b` array.

Comment: do you know you can loop/iterate an array?

Comment: Yes, of course I tried, it works, I am asking if there is a native method for this.

Comment: @cincplug Always add the attempts/code in the question. Saves from down votes.

Comment: @Tushar, thanks, it is prettier now I believe. But the added data is kind of irrelevant :)

Comment: @cincplug: That added data doesn't really add value to the question. What Tushar meant was that you should show what you tried to solve this yourself, first.

Comment: @Cerbrus Ok, I added an example of what I did, though it doesn't add any value to anything, because you already answered the question, more detailed. I asked very clearly, is there a way for this beside iterating over array and pushing members into array. My code worked all the time, I asked if there is shorter method.

Comment: There's not much room for improvement on something of this scale.

Comment: So, @cincplug, did either of the answers answer your question?

Comment: @Cerbrus Not really, in a sense that I was hoping there is solution without iterating over an array. But, your code seems to be better in terms of performance, so I'll pick that one. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, iterate over `a`, and add all items from `b` at one of `a`'s indexes to `c`:

```js
var a = [0, 3, 5, 100],
    b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
    c = [];

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  if(b[a[i]] !== undefined)
    c.push(b[a[i]]);
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(c));
```

Comment: @Tushar: ES6? I don't think that's a good idea quite yet. Also, that doesn't handle indexes in `a` that are out of range on `b`.

Comment: Didn't actually mean ES6, the idea is the same. `var c = a.map(function(e) {
    return b[e];
});` or `var c = []; a.forEach(function(e) {
    c.push(b[e]);
});`.

Comment: Still, `map` doesn't work with faulty indexes, and `forEach` literally does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over `b` using `a` to construct the filtering function:

```
function byIndex(indexes) {
  return function(elem, index) {
    return indexes.indexOf(index) >= 0;
  }
}

a = [0, 3, 16];
b = [...some array...];
var filtered = b.filter(byIndex(a));
```

Comment: A small disadvantage here is that you're iterating over the complete data set (`b`), and for each of those iterations, you're iterating over `a`. It's not very significant unless the data set is absolutely massive, but still...

Comment: ^^^ Complexity `n * m`

Comment: Indeed, performance would go south the more "sparse" the indexes are compared to the whole dataset.